# function error handling in Swift 2

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

With the following code I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'inout NSError?' (aka 'inout Optional') to expected argument type '()'

and it's on this line of code:

```
if device.lockForConfiguration(&error)
```

Here's the rest of the code:

```
func focusWithMode(focusMode:AVCaptureFocusMode, exposureMode:AVCaptureExposureMode, point:CGPoint, monitorSubjectAreaChange:Bool){

    dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue!, {
        var device: AVCaptureDevice! = self.videoDeviceInput!.device
        var error: NSError? = nil

        if device.lockForConfiguration(&error){
            if device.focusPointOfInterestSupported && device.isFocusModeSupported(focusMode){
                device.focusMode = focusMode
                device.focusPointOfInterest = point
            }
            if device.exposurePointOfInterestSupported && device.isExposureModeSupported(exposureMode){
                device.exposurePointOfInterest = point
                device.exposureMode = exposureMode
            }
            device.subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = monitorSubjectAreaChange
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: My guess is Swift 2 and try/catch vs error but the OP is being coy to test us.

Comment: @jtbandes This is the error: Cannot convert value of type 'inout NSError?' (aka 'inout Optional<NSError>') to expected argument type '()'

Comment: Don't tell me — tell everyone. [Edit] your question and put in the required information. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InSwift 2 error handling has changed from `NSError` in-out parameters to try/catch (not exceptions).

I think this is a correct conversion from `NSError` to try/catch:

```
func focusWithMode(focusMode:AVCaptureFocusMode, exposureMode:AVCaptureExposureMode, point:CGPoint, monitorSubjectAreaChange:Bool){
    dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue!, {
        var device: AVCaptureDevice! = self.videoDeviceInput!.device
        var error: NSError? = nil

        do {
           try device.lockForConfiguration()
            if device.focusPointOfInterestSupported && device.isFocusModeSupported(focusMode){
                device.focusMode = focusMode
                device.focusPointOfInterest = point
            }
            if device.exposurePointOfInterestSupported && device.isExposureModeSupported(exposureMode){
                device.exposurePointOfInterest = point
                device.exposureMode = exposureMode
            }
            device.subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = monitorSubjectAreaChange
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
        catch {
            print("Locked error!")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you! Only problem now is that it's giving me an error "Expected pattern" on the line `let try locked = device.lockForConfiguration()`

Comment: Ok so I figured it out and the answer above is really close. Remove `let try locked =` and replace with just `try`. Remove `if locked` and it's corresponding curly brackets. That's it!

Comment: @Wheeler Preddy Updated answer.